# executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Trying to figure out why my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:ubuntu-focal
RUN apt-get -qq -y update && \
    apt-get -qq -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -qq -y install curl ca-certificates python3-pip exiftool mkvtoolnix
RUN pip3 install gallery-dl yt-dlp
WORKDIR /mydir
COPY gallery-dl.ps1 .
ENTRYPOINT ["gallery-dl.ps1"]
```

throws the following error when run:

```
> docker build --file gallery-dl.dockerfile --tag psa .
> docker run -it --rm --name psatest psa
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "gallery-dl.ps1": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

I've tried seemingly everything: using CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT, modifying the COPY dest to `./gallery-dl.ps1`, changing the order of commands.
I've prepended `#!/usr/bin/pwsh -File` to the ps1 script (as instructed in a different question of mine).
When I attach into the container and ls it shows all of my mounts and `gallery-dl.ps` itself where it should be and where I'm supposedly calling it:

```
PS /mydir> ls
conf  gallery-dl.ps1  output
```

The only thing that works is removing WORKDIR but I actually need that, I can't just run everything in root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things: Make sure the file is marked as executable. And since `/mydir` isn't in your path, you need to tell Docker to look for the script in the current directory by adding `./` in front of the name.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:ubuntu-focal
RUN apt-get -qq -y update && \
    apt-get -qq -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -qq -y install curl ca-certificates python3-pip exiftool mkvtoolnix
RUN pip3 install gallery-dl yt-dlp
WORKDIR /mydir
COPY gallery-dl.ps1 .
RUN chmod +x gallery-dl.ps1
ENTRYPOINT ["./gallery-dl.ps1"]
```

Comment: Oh my God, it was the `./` bit. Thank you, I struggled with this so much haha. I don't need to prepend that bit on Windows, but I guess it's required on Linux.

Comment: Yes, Linux only looks in the PATH directories for executables unlike Windows which also looks in the current directory.